# spark streaming stop without stopping java spark context

Tags: spark-streaming

Anyone knows how to stop spark streaming without stopping Java spark context ?

I already tried to give `false` argument in `stop()` function of spark streaming but it was  not working . When I restarted spark streaming it created new spark streaming with previous one. Due to previous one streaming it didn't free core of system.

So I am getting stuck to close spark streaming without stopping Java spark context .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check with this method (`stop(boolean stopSparkContext, boolean stopGracefully)`) with `stopSparkContext` as a false, it will stop streaming context gracefully.